# mySQL using 100% CPU

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group, cpu-usage

I have a PHP application that is running on a LAMP stack. This application makes an API call back to the server via javascript to get more data to display on the screen every second. When there are a number of users using it at the same time, say 80, mySQL slams the CPU to 100% until the application is finished.

What am I using:

- mySQL 5.7.31
- Ubuntu 18.04

Running on an EC2 instance of size m5.xlarge

- 4 vCPU
- 16G RAM
- network BW up to 10Gbps

I used advice from percona about tweaking the mySQL parameters, they say most of 5.7's have great defaults expect a couple that are dependent on your hardware, so my mySQL config looks like this

mysqld.cnf

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
character-set-client-handshake = false #force encoding to uft8
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
sql_mode = 'IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 256M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 11G # (adjust value here, 50%-70% of total RAM)
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
```

### Percona Monitoring and Management

I am also running Percona Monitoring and Management which gives me a great view as to what is going on.

So when I have the 100% CPU this is what I have determined

1. CPU is 100%, and in user space - this is because my innoDB buffer pool size is so large all the data is in memory so HDD is not being hit therefore no IO
   [image]
2. Max number of connections is not being hit - 100 connections out of 150 is being used for the duration
   [image]
3. Slow query log shows nothing in there
   [image]
4. Top counters seem to be com_select
   [image]
5. And top handlers read_next and read_rnd_next
   [image]
6. The query cache shows nothing is being cached
   [image]

So this points to a query that is causing this issue. PMM has a nice Query Analytics to see the queries causing issues, this is what it shows
[image]

So the top 2 queries are the culprits. Reading a lot online everyone points to indexes as the most common cause of the CPU load, but these tables have indexes. So here are the 2 queries and table definitions and indexes for each and the explain statements show they are using the indexes as well?

### Query 1

```
SELECT
  `tick`,
  VALUE
FROM
  `stored_path_data`
WHERE
  `stored_path_ID` = ?
  AND `tick` <= ?
  AND `tick` >= ?
ORDER BY
  `tick`
```

```
mysql> explain stored_path_data;
+----------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID             | int(11)                       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| stored_path_ID | int(11)                       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tick           | int(11)                       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value          | decimal(18,7)                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type           | enum('interpolated','manual') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> show indexes from stored_path_data;
+------------------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| stored_path_data |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | ID             | A         |      316875 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stored_path_data |          0 | compound |            1 | stored_path_ID | A         |         997 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stored_path_data |          0 | compound |            2 | tick           | A         |      316875 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stored_path_data |          1 | tick     |            1 | tick           | A         |        1771 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
mysql> explain SELECT   tick,value FROM stored_path_data WHERE stored_path_ID = 4887   AND `tick` <= 240   AND `tick` >= 0 ORDER BY   `tick`;
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stored_path_data | NULL       | range | compound,tick | tick | 4       | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

### Query 2

```
SELECT
  `spd`.`stored_path_ID`,
  `spd`.`value`
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      `stored_path_ID`,
      MAX (`tick`) AS `max_tick`
    FROM
      `stored_path_data`
    WHERE
      `stored_path_ID` IN (...)
      AND `tick` <= ?
    GROUP BY
      `stored_path_ID`
  ) AS `temp`
  INNER JOIN `stored_path_data` AS `spd` ON `temp`.`stored_path_ID` = `spd`.`stored_path_ID`
WHERE
  `spd`.`tick` = `temp`.`max_tick`
```

```
mysql> explain SELECT   `spd`.`stored_path_ID`,   `spd`.`value` FROM   (     SELECT       `stored_path_ID`,       MAX (`tick`) AS `max_tick`     FROM       `stored_path_data`     WHERE       `stored_path_ID` IN (4883,4884,4885,4886,4887)       AND `tick` <= 240     GROUP BY       `stored_path_ID`   ) AS `temp`   INNER JOIN `stored_path_data` AS `spd` ON `temp`.`stored_path_ID` = `spd`.`stored_path_ID` WHERE   `spd`.`tick` = `temp`.`max_tick`;
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref                                               | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | spd              | NULL       | ALL   | compound,tick | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                              |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>       | NULL       | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 9       | tradingsim.spd.stored_path_ID,tradingsim.spd.tick |    2 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | stored_path_data | NULL       | index | compound,tick | compound    | 8       | NULL                                              |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Same table so indexes are the same. Above also includes the explains on each query.

There are 2 things i noticed with these queries.

1. Query 1 is using a range, but has compound index on tick and stored_path_ID
2. Query 2 is using a temp table - I have tried improving the query without the temp table and it helps a little but CPU is still slammed at 100%

### mySQLTuner

I then ran mysqltuner https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl and this is the advice it gave

```
...
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Add some space to /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2012 mountpoint.
    Add some space to /snap/core/10126 mountpoint.
    Add some space to /snap/core/10185 mountpoint.
    Cleanup files from /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2012 mountpoint or reformat you filesystem.
    Cleanup files from /snap/core/10126 mountpoint or reformat you filesystem.
    Cleanup files from /snap/core/10185 mountpoint or reformat you filesystem.
    setup swappiness lower or equals to 10
    setup Max running number events greater than 1M
    Check all table collations are identical for all tables in tradingsim database.
    Limit charset for column to one charset if possible for tradingsim database.
    Limit collations for column to one collation if possible for tradingsim database.
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`instances` MODIFY `name` CHAR(0) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`instances` MODIFY `date_display_format` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`instruments` MODIFY `instrument_group_ID` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`news` MODIFY `title` TINYTEXT NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`news` MODIFY `body` TEXT NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `secondname` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `second_email` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `work_phone` CHAR(0) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `mobile_phone` CHAR(0) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `home_phone` CHAR(0) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `username` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `photo_url` CHAR(0) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `email_type` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `fax_number` CHAR(0) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `mts_priority` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `silent_login_group_ID` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `marketing_feedback` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `person_type` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `left_company` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `immutable_ID` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `media_server_ID` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `jobtitle` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `rdr_training_requirements` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `rdr_qualifications_correct` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `rdr_study_qualifications_correct` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `har` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `personal_email` CHAR(0);
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`stored_path_data` MODIFY `ID` MEDIUMINT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`stored_path_data` MODIFY `value` DECIMAL(18, 7) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`trader_responses` MODIFY `instance_ID` CHAR(0);
    Remove unused indexes.
    Restrict Host for 'simulations'@% to simulations@SpecificDNSorIp
    UPDATE mysql.user SET host ='SpecificDNSorIp' WHERE user='simulations' AND host ='%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: 
    Read this before increasing for MariaDB https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/optimizing-table_open_cache/
    This is MyISAM only table_cache scalability problem, InnoDB not affected.
    See more details here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49177
    This bug already fixed in MySQL 5.7.9 and newer MySQL versions.
    Beware that open_files_limit (5000) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache (2000)
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: 
Variables to adjust:
    vm.swappiness <= 10 (echo 10 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness)
    fs.aio-max-nr > 1M (echo 1048576 > /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr)
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    table_open_cache (> 2000)
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=1G) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=11)
```

I tried those adjustments but still no luck.

The only last thing I can think of is the following

1. Using a cache - memcached or redis
2. Moving mySQL off the server and onto something like RDS where I can up hardware but thats expensive

Can anyone help suggest what I could do in this situation, am totally stumped!! I didnt think that 100 connections a second was that big a deal. Could I be hitting table lock issues? though this is what the stats showed me about that

[image]

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

### EDIT

I have found this really interesting article about max connections and scaling with mySQL - https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-connection-handling-and-scaling/

And if you go down to the bottom of the page to the summary the item I think that is relevent to my situation is

> Rule of thumb: Max number of connections = 4 times available CPU cores

So based on my max usage of 100 max connections this means I should aim for a server with 25 CPU cores OR re-architect the platform. I think that is where this may be headed. I am going to load test a server of this size and see how that fairs.

### Edit 2

```
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE NAME = 'stored_path_data';
+------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name             | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| stored_path_data | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |    0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |   4194304 |        5084417 | 2020-10-29 06:11:01 | NULL        | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Conclusions

Just to help people if they come to this looking for answers (and dont want to read through all the comments), @RickJames came out with the solution to this problem. It did end up being indexes, but something called a covering index, which I didnt know existed, so creating the index and then running ANALYZE TABLE fixed my issue.

```
CREATE INDEX covering ON stored_path_data(stored_path_ID, tick, value);
ANALYZE TABLE stored_path_data;
```

I tried my suggestion above of increasing CPUs and ran 90 concurrent users on 36 CPU EC2 instance and its a complete overkill, where before the index all 36 CPUs were maxed out to 100%. I will be reducing my hardware to something more suitable for the application, but once again thanks @RickJames for your help

Comment: while on AWS , and less expensive than RDS, you could provision an EBS for your data with provisioned IOPS.  and crank-up the IOPS as your platform evolves/needs.

Comment: `This application makes an API call back to the server via javascript to get more data to display on the screen every second` - this is never ever going to scale. You must use an alternative way for notifications, such as an event bridge.

Comment: Thanks YvesLeBorg - will an IOPS provisioned EBS volume be quicker than RAM? Currently I think its all stored in memory and being read from there rather than disk so not sure if a new EBS volume will make much of a difference?

Comment: Thanks Shadow - yes I hear you, but this is an old application I have inherited and dont have the budget to completely re-architect it unfortunately.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have problems going forward when you have multiple concurrent users. Consider at least increasing the intervals between the queries to a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Shadow. But what do you think is the problem? Too many concurrent connections on the database? I thought mySQL could handle that and InnoDB can handle multiple reads too? I guess I am trying to work out what the exact issue is before just changing a large portion of the platform. Also I cant increase the interval it has to be every 1 second, unless I do more work in the client with a js framework or something.

Comment: Since you are using php, your application will most likely create a connection to mysql, execute a few queries,return the resultset to the client, then close the mysql connection, then start all over again. It is possible that a cycle does not even finish for a user, but your application starts it over again in parallel with the previos one (1 sec is not an awful lot of time). This results in a significant overhead on mysql and indexing and query optimisation can only help so much! This way you will exhaust the 100 database connections pretty soon!

Comment: Thanks for your comments Shadow, and you are right. If you see my edit to the question I found a blog where they spoke about needing x number CPU based on the max connections. I was only using 4 CPUs but if I am wanting 100 concurrent connections then I would need at min 25 CPUs to handle this. Looks like I may not be able to optimize it further, its either 1) throw hardware at it 2) re-architect it, do you agree?

Comment: Or both :) yes, I firmly believe you must rearchitect this application! Unfortunately, if you search on the Internet how to do notifications with php and mysql, then the polling solution like yours still come up - even here on SO. But this setup is a dead end. 4 connections per core - this depends on a lot of factors, you have to test what's the right number for your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You can't tune your way out of a performance problem"

Query 1 *might* be helped by adding a "covering" index to `stored_path_data`: `INDEX(stored_path_ID, tick, value)`

If the `EXPLAIN` continues to use some other index instead, then drop that other index.  This index is "covering" and optimal for the query, in many ways.

Query 2:

```
    INNER JOIN  `stored_path_data` AS `spd`
        ON `temp`.`stored_path_ID` = `spd`.`stored_path_ID`
    WHERE  `spd`.`tick` = `temp`.`max_tick`
```

-->

```
    INNER JOIN  `stored_path_data` AS `spd`
        ON `temp`.`stored_path_ID` = `spd`.`stored_path_ID`
       AND `spd`.`tick` = `temp`.`max_tick`
```

I don't expect any difference, but the latter shows your intent.  Meanwhile, I added a tag having to do with "groupwise max".

What's with the `CHAR(0)`???

```
ALTER TABLE `tradingsim`.`persons` MODIFY `second_email` CHAR(0);
```

Drop `long_query_time` to `1`; maybe then you will get something useful in the slowlog.

`query_cache_size        = 256M` is high, lower to 50M or turn off the QC.  It tends to be a CPU hog on production systems.  (The graph seems contradictory -- high activity, but zero counts??)

I hope you are using InnoDB, not MyISAM.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

I hate graphs without units.  "Top Command Counters" -- are they "per second"?  A few hundred `SELECTs` per second should not be as much problem as you are seeing.  (Maybe the above `SHOWs` will help.)  What does "75.69 Load" mean?  "Load Average?  Seems % of something?  What is missing from TOTAL?  237 queries, but under 20 in the list??

OK, I figured out Load -- it's query_time * query_count.  This is a good metric (and the numbers are not very relevant).  53.47 probably means that half the time the server is working on that first query.

Summary Tables -- I don't under the semantics of `tick`, etc, but *maybe* building and maintaining a "summary table" would be beneficial.  In some situations, it speeds up queries by 10x.

Comment: thanks so much for your suggestions I will try the new covering index and adjust the second query. The char(0) I think is because the table doesnt have any data in those fields, so they arent being used. Yes I am using InnoDB not myISAM. I know thats why I am so lost why for such small numbers I am getting such bad performance. I have thought about summary table possibly. The tick field think of it like second. So at second 1 there are values then second 2 the values have changed (time series), so cant really summarise that data needs to pull it out each time.

Comment: just adding that covering index has brought my CPU usage down from 100% to approx 85% which is a vast improvement so thank you. I might give Wilson Hauck parameter adjustments a go as well and see if that improves things even more.

Comment: can you explain this. I added the covering index you mentioned and running it on a later cored server (See my comment in edit 1) - when adding load all CPUs were maxed out again 100%, I checked the indexes and their Cardinality was 0 so I ran ANALYZE TABLE and all of a sudden that brought everything into place and now CPUs are averaging about 25% (I have 36 CPUs) - can you explain this?

Comment: @AndrewKew - Sometimes, _but not often_, the "statistics" get messed up in InnoDB.  `ANALYZE TABLE` recomputes them.  As you found out, it is cheap and easy to run.  So, feel free to run it as the first line of defense.  But don't hold your breath.  It helps so rarely that I don't think to mention it.  The Optimizer uses the stats to decide which of drastically different ways to evaluate a query.  So, it _can_ make a big difference.

Comment: thanks for your answer Rick and for anyone else out there the covering index is what has given me DRAMATIC improvements. I need to load test it a bit more but the 100% CPU has gone. I also needed to analyze the table again to fix the Cardinality=0 but once those 2 tasks were complete its given the server a new lease of life. I am currently running 90 concurrent users on a server with 36 cores (based on my edit 1) and its hardly being used, so I will be reducing the hardware and retesting but the covering index has been a lifesaver so thanks Rick.

Answer (score 0):

Forget mysql tuner - it will likely do you more harm than good unless you already know what you are doing.

For the first two queries in your QAN screenshot, you need an index on `stored_path_data(stored_path_ID, tick)`. That should make a huge amount of difference to the performance and CPU consumption.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Gordan. But I think that compound index is already on the table if you look at the indexes under the query 1? There is a compound index or am I reading that incorrectly?

Comment: I created that index CREATE INDEX path_tick ON stored_path_data(stored_path_ID, tick); and as I expected when looking at indexes on that table I now have 2 compound indexes on the same fields. SO I think that index already existed. It was the first place I looked when there was CPU load.

Comment: The cardinality on your indexes of 0 is very suspicious. It implies your table statistics are broken. Run `ANALYZE TABLE stored_path_data;` and check again.

Comment: Thanks Gordan. Seems like its ok, this is the response: tradingsim.stored_path_data | analyze | status   | OK, but you are right that is weird that its 0. Must have been some weirdness when I made the post looking now and they are not zero -  I will edit the post with the new output of the table

Comment: Add an index hint: `... FROM stored_path_data USE INDEX (compound) ...`. see that should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

In your EC2 Parameters Group, consider the following

```
thread_cache_size=100  # since you have average 93 connections
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8  # to avoid mutex contention with your 11G data
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% CPU cycles used for function
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 or request through a ticket for your SSD data device
```

Good luck, let us know your outcome, please.

Comment: @AndrewKew Posting your complete MySQLTuner report to pastebin.com (after 24 hours of uptime) and sharing the link would include very helpful information.  Even though some people suggest it is totally useless.  We would know which engines you were using and the table counts by engine and many more useful details for those that have time to understand the report.

Comment: @AndrewKew Please post SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE NAME = 'stored_path_data';

Comment: thanks for your tips. I have added the show table status to my original post and here is the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/QNj6q4AV also I am not using RDS so cant adjust parameter groups but can change my mySQL settings to the above suggestions? Or are there EC2 parameter groups as well as RDS?

Comment: @AndrewKew A) In your EDIT 2 from a few days ago, we can see your STSWM for stored_path_data.  Is there a reason the table has '0 rows' reported? B) how did you run MySQLTuner to acquire all the details?  C) On EC2 you should be able to apply suggestions in your my.cnf file - or equivalent.

Comment: A) that was fixed by running ANALYZE TABLE stored_path_data; B) Not sure what you mean by how did I run it? C) Yes correct I did make adjustments to my my.cnf file but to be honest the suggestions didnt help much, the covering index did the trick